# Robinia Leaf Problem

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Someone may know the children's game with a robinia leaf. The leaves are pinnate with 7–21 oval leaflets and the game works like the following:

Ever player picks a leaflet, which is then marked by cutting of the tip of that leaf. Next, someone picks a random number between 1 and 10, lets say 5. Then the game leader starts counting down the leaflets clockwise, starting from the bottom left. If he reaches the chosen number (in this case 5) he removes this leaflet and starts counting again from 1 at the following leaflet. If he reaches the bottom right he just continues counting clockwise at the bottom left. The important part is, that every removed leaflet is not accounted for anymore. So after a while all leaflets are removed until only a single leaflet remains. If one of the players was lucky to chose exactly this last leaflet, he is the winner of the game.

So, my question now is: Is there an analytic way to determine the "winning" leaflet by taking into account the initial number of leaflets and the chosen number?

Comment: Hm - could someone tell me, why my question was voted down? Is the problem unclear or too obvious? I would really like to know the answer. So, I would be grateful for any hints to the problem or recommondations so I can improve my question.

Comment: This is essentially the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem); it has a nice solution when the chosen number is $2$ and is rather messy otherwise.

Comment: Great! Thank you! - Would you convert your comment to an answer, so I can mark it accordingly?

Comment: Done, and you’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem); it has a nice solution when the chosen number is $2$ and is rather messy otherwise.